# No package names in javadocs

Tags: java, javadoc

My javadocs display the full package name for every parameter and return type for a method. For example:

```
compareResults(java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>>)
```

In the Java api reference, ArrayList etc is not prepended by the full package name, it's just ArrayList.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [-noqualifier option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#noqualifier) which works like this:

```
-noqualifier java.*:com.sun.*
```